# CodeIgniter Ion-Auth Check if logged in

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

my question is how i can load a specific navigation (as view) when the user is logged in. If he´s not logged in, another navigation should be loaded.

I dunno how i can do this :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's really simple. You can check if a user is logged in with the logged_in() (see: http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/#logged_in) and then load the view accordingly

```php
if ($this->ion_auth->logged_in())
{
    $this->load->view('loggedin_nav');
}
else 
{
    $this->load->view('NOT_loggedin_nav');
}
```

Comment: Can i do this in my controller? I want to load it in my controller.. Otherwise i´ll get a lot of errors cause i´m using helpers that need information from ion auth.. (username, email etc..)

Comment: Depends an how your controller and/or views are set up. But in general you could do this in your controller, because you can load multiple views in your controller, see [User-Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
if( ! $this->ion_auth->logged_in){
\\ do something }
```